# Why does 'The virus went out of control' sound wrong, when it is grammatically correct?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage, prepositional-phrases

My first instinct was to change 'the virus went out of control' to 'the virus was out of control.' My supposition was confirmed by other people who are native English speakers. Yet we can't figure out why this is so. Similarly, 'the computer went out of control' sounds less acceptable than 'was'. Yet 'the fire went out of control' seems less unacceptable than the rest...

We were wondering if it was an issue of agency, as a virus has no consciousness. Whereas fire and computer would be instruments???

Two of the meanings of the word ‘go’, are, from Oxford:

A) To pass into or be in a specified state, especially an undesirable one: the food is going bad 
B) To proceed or turn out in a specified way: At first all went well.

So the use of 'went' should be acceptable.

The issue seems to be an instinctive rejection of a change of state, from under control to out of control, and a preference for a statement to the effect of an unchangeable status as implied by the word 'was'.

Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: _The virus went out of control_ does seem to imply that at some earlier point it was under control.

Comment: Yes, but I can't see why that is at all wrong either. Viruses can be kept under control - in terms of lab conditions, successful epidemiological and medical measures and so on... I get what you mean though.

Comment: *Similarly, 'the computer went out of control' sounds less right than 'was'. Yet 'the fire went out of control' seems less wrong than the rest.* -- Probably because there is no motion when a computer **is** out of control... it enters a state, whereas with a fire or a virus, there is progression/movement. (Otherwise, I agree with Killing Time above.)

Comment: That sounds right, but doesn't a virus move within cells and bodies? And spread?

Comment: 'The simulant went out of control' sounds about as natural(!) as I can contrive. Even 'John went out of control' is less satisfying to my ears. I think an agent that is human-connected, a robot or other complicated contraption, is the preferred subject. A strong hint of previously being under control (so a human agent isn't perhaps the best choice), but a slight hint at personification ('went' hinting at storming off).

Comment: John went out of control probably sounds off, because we have a collocation 'lost control' which is more common in usage.

Comment: Compare *the cat got out of the house* with *the cat went out of the house*. We know that cats are independent creatures, and that sometimes their goals are different from our own.  *Got* carries a slight connotation of agency and opposition, so it pairs well with *control*. In contrast, *went out of control* is more passive. When a car goes out of control, we attribute this to some failure of a human agent, not the will of the car. A virus is somewhere between a car and a cat. It’s agency might be figurative, like *fire*, but it can seem real, especially now.

Comment: @Keliviete: "*but doesn't a virus move within cells and bodies?"* That is not usually how it is viewed: it multiplies in situ. -- *"And spread?"* again we are back to the idea that the "spreading" was at one time, "under control."

Comment: It's important to realise that < go = (A) To pass into or be in a specified state, especially an undesirable one: _the food is going bad_ //  (B) To proceed or turn out in a specified way: _At first all went well_ > does **not** guarantee < So the use of 'went' should be acceptable > *John went asleep. Later he went awake.' // 'The black is safe.' 'The black went safe'. But 'The pink is available.'  *'The pink went available.'  A dictionary definition for a word W means 'W may have this meaning when used in say a sentence', **not** 'W may always be used to convey this meaning, in any context'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on context.  "In the second week of March the virus went out of control" implies that that point in time was notable.  "In the second week of March the virus was out of control" tells you very little, absent some info on the state of "control" prior to that time.

Comment: We're tempted to say 'the virus went viral'.

Comment: I think this seems the most likely to me, because if I add an extension to the sentence, then that niggling sense of wrongness vanishes. Some sort of transition (A to B) happening makes it ok. Essentially I felt the sentence was missing something.

E.g. (Situation A) The virus went out of control killing the patient (situation B). 
E.g. (Situation A) She stopped taking the medication and the virus went out of control (situation B).

Answer (score 0):

The two possibilities are covered in the [OALD definition](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/control_1#control_idmg_2) of "**be/get/run/etc. out of control**, that is, "*to be or become impossible to manage or to control*". It is clear that the "etc." makes "go out of control" a synonymous phrase for those of the second part (get/run/etc.); those latter all indicate an onset ("to become" implies a change from one state to an another and there must be, at this time of becoming, the beginning of the new state) whereas the first (be) indicates a mere point in time while the situation characterized by an unrestrained state lasts.

If one accepts "was out of control", it is then irrationnal to reject "went out …"; there is nothing involved other than a difference between a state at a given time between its start and its end and the same state at its quasi-beginning (the onset): if we allow a verb as characterizing a particular state we must as well allow as correct those that prescribe a change from that state to another or, as in the present case, from another to that state;  changes are natural occurrences in this context. Therefore, from the point of view of the OP the problem has to be  somewhere else, not in the choice of verb.

It is found from an examination of the usage  of "go out of control" and "be out of control" that they are very general expressions that are applied to about anything that is susceptible of evolution so as to indicate an excess in this evolution or something abnormal.

cars (generally crashes)
aircraft (dangerous divergence from trajectory)
nuclear reactors (overheating in the extreme)
cannons (blowing up)
red hot sheets (striking and wounding workers)
fire  (unrestrained expansion)
blood sugar (unrestrained increase)
horse (wild behaviour that the rider can suppress)
(more general) things
everything
situation
administrative measures (executive compensation)
process
project
sex and drug bit
riots
men (violent behaviour)
men (extravagant behaviour)
men ( loss of calm in inordinate situations)
children (unruly behaviour)
someone's anxiety
temper
overcrowding (overpopulation)
animal population (unrestrainable increase)
factor
lyrics (displaying sexual immaturity)
currencies
systems
…

I can't see anything else to explain why this construction could seem abnormal than a case of unconscious and  subjective reaction due to a difficulty in conceiving the virus as an agent: I suppose that "The infection/epidemy went out of control." does not cause this uneasiness; after all it is very much like "Inflation went out of control." ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inflation+went+out+of+control&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinflation%20went%20out%20of%20control%3B%2Cc0); inflation is even more deprived of consciousness than viruses.),  "Crime went out of control.", "Those criminals went out of control and it became impossible to trace their acts of embezzlement back to them.", etc.
One possible difficulty could be in the additional conceptualization that is necessary in 
passing from "the virus", which evokes outright the concept of a single entity with its particularity, to the "swarm" of those entities disseminated into a multitude of victims, this being really what "the virus" stands for.

*Precisions*

1/ Fires that are accidents justify fully the expression "go out of control" which in that case means that the personnel in charge of putting the fire out or from gaining too much ground is unable to keep it from spreading. Almost all cases of such fires that go out of control are not fires as instuments (fire in the wooden stove and so on) but accidents or the result of mischievous or war acts.

[ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8C0OoG5e12AC&pg=PA363&dq=%22went+out+of+control%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-x9-mxtvoAhVJDmMBHRoWCNo4ZBDoAQgmMAA#v=onepage&q=%22went%20out%20of%20control%22&f=false)... of Thoreau, and she said, 'He was a real bum.' " "Thoreau actually started a couple of forest fires in his time," Blanchette admits. "One in Concord. The other on Mt. Washington. When the fires went out of control, Thoreau just walked away.

2/ The sense to be retained for "go" is rather this one (not "be in a specified state", but merely "pass into a specified state", to be verified in [OALD, 17](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/go_1?q=go). "B)" does not apply at all.

> [intransitive] used in many expressions to show that somebody/something has reached a particular state/is no longer in a particular state
>   *That colour has gone out of fashion.*

Comment: 'If one accepts "was out of control", it is then irration[]al to reject "went out …" ' But English _is_ often irrational. 'We were out of milk.' / '*We went out of milk. // 'We were out of danger.' / *'We went out of danger.' // 'He was out of patience with inaccurate answers.' / *"He went out of patience with inaccurate answers.' // Arguing from analogy is often unhelpful. Idioms by definition behave with unpredictability, and English is full of them (that's a hyperbole).

Comment: Perhaps it is just a usage thing... it's quite likely.

Comment: I do appreciate the effort and sheer length of the answer you provided! :D Thanks!

Comment: @Kellviete I hope it added  at least one little thing useful to your understanding.

Comment: Definitely! I hadn't even considered the conceptualisation problem. 

_"If one accepts "was out of control", it is then irrationnal to reject "went out ...Therefore, from the point of view of the OP the problem has to be somewhere else, not in the choice of verb."_

This was pretty much the thing; the change in the state and lack of any indication of said change in the sentence was what the hang up was about. 'Went' made me unconsciously look for the highlighted important previous state (as mentioned in Hot lick's answer) and 'was' didn't...Irrational may be right, or just pattern seeking?

Comment: @Kellviete I should say that this "highlighted previous state" appears to me rather obvious, it is just a state where the virus is under control, wouldn't you say?